# Speeding up $or query in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, nosql

I have a collection of 1.8 billion records stored in mongodb, where each record looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54c1a013715faf2cc0047c77"),
    "service_type" : "JE",
    "receiver_id" : NumberLong("865438083645"),
    "time" : ISODate("2012-12-05T23:07:36Z"),
    "duration" : 24,
    "service_description" : "NQ",
    "receiver_cell_id" : null,
    "location_id" : "658_55525",
    "caller_id" : NumberLong("475035504705")
}
```

I need to get all the records for 2 million specific users (I have the users of interest id in a text file) and process it before I write the results to a database. I have indices on the receiver_id and on caller_id (each is part of a single index).

The current procedure I have is as the following:

```
for user in list_of_2million_users:
    user_records = collection.find({ "$or" : [ { "caller_id": user }, { "receiver_id" : user } ] })
    for record in user_records:
        process(record)
```

However, it takes 15 seconds on average to consume the user_records cursor (the process function is very simple with low running time). This will not be feasible to process 2 million users. Any suggestions to speed up the $or query? as it seems to be the most time-consuming step.

```
db.call_records.find({ "$or" : [ { "caller_id": 125091840205 }, { "receiver_id" : 125091840205 } ] }).explain()
{
    "clauses" : [
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor caller_id_1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 401,
            "nscannedObjects" : 401,
            "nscanned" : 401,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "caller_id" : [
                    [
                        125091840205,
                        125091840205
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor receiver_id_1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 383,
            "nscannedObjects" : 383,
            "nscanned" : 383,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "receiver_id" : [
                    [
                        125091840205,
                        125091840205
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "cursor" : "QueryOptimizerCursor",
    "n" : 784,
    "nscannedObjects" : 784,
    "nscanned" : 784,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 784,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 784,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "nYields" : 753,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 31057,
    "server" : "some_server:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

And this is the collection stats:

```
 db.call_records.stats()
{
    "ns" : "stc_cdrs.call_records",
    "count" : 1825338618,
    "size" : 438081268320,
    "avgObjSize" : 240,
    "storageSize" : 468641284752,
    "numExtents" : 239,
    "nindexes" : 3,
    "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 0,
    "userFlags" : 1,
    "totalIndexSize" : 165290709024,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 73450862016,
        "caller_id_1" : 45919923504,
        "receiver_id_1" : 45919923504
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I am running Ubuntu server with 125GB of RAM.

Note that I will run this analysis only once (not periodic thing I will do).

Comment: Can you post an explain for one of the `user_records` queries? One that your code requires 15 seconds to consume?

Comment: edited my question to include the output for .explain()

Comment: The result set is small and the query is properly indexed. How do you know that MongoDB/pymongo is the performance problem here? Do you see the slow operations in the mongod logs?

Comment: @wdberkeley Yes .. it takes almost 15 seconds to get the results as seen in the mongod logs :<

Comment: 1) The whole database has 400GB, much larger than your RAM. So while querying the index itself is fast, it will need to load the records themselves from disk. 2) consider using short field names in the database and only mapping them to meaningful names during deserialization. That should reduce the size of the collection by 1/3 or so.

Comment: Take at look at the suggestions from harshad's answer. If you want to figure out what is making the database slow, probably the next thing to do is look at page faults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the indices on `caller_id` and `receiver_id` are a single compound index, this query will do a collection scan instead of an index scan. Make sure they are both part of a separate index, i.e.:

```
db.user_records.ensureIndex({caller_id:1})
db.user_records.ensureIndex({receiver_id:1})
```

You can confirm that your query is doing an index scan in the mongo shell:

```
db.user_records.find({'$or':[{caller_id:'example'},{receiver_id:'example'}]}).explain()
```

If the explain plan returns its cursor type as BTreeCursor, you're using an index scan. If it says BasicCursor, you're doing a collection scan which is not good.

It would also be interesting to know the size of each index. For best query performances, both indices should be completely loaded into RAM. If the indices are so large that only one (or neither!) of them fit into RAM, you will have to page them in from disk to look up the results. If they're too big to fit in your RAM, your options are not too great, basically either splitting up your collection in some manner and re-indexing it, or getting more RAM. You could always get an AWS RAM-heavy instance just for the purpose of this analysis, since this is a one-off thing.

Comment: both keys are part of a separate index. and I get BtreeCursor type. The index size is as follows: '"indexSizes" : {
  "_id_" : 73450862016,
  "caller_id_1" : 45919923504,
  "receiver_id_1" : 45919923504,
  "caller_id_1_receiver_id_1" : 576743216
 }' the server I am using has plenty of RAM.

Comment: How did you get those index sizes? I'm a little reluctant to believe those are the actual sizes of your indices as each one is 45 gigabytes. I would consider a server with 32GB of ram to have plenty but that couldn't even fit one index. To read more about this, I'll direct you to [mongoDB's docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram/).

Comment: I got them from the explain() of the query. The server I am using has 125G RAM available. I updated my question to include those.

Comment: @JedEstep About 25 byte per index entry doesn't sound that implausible.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in MongoDB, though I had the similar problem & following solutions helped me tackle the problem. Hope it helps you too.

Query is using indexes and scanning exact documents, so there are no issues with your indexing, though I'll suggest you to:

First of all try to see the status of command: `mongostat --discover`

See for the parameters such as `page faults` & `index miss`.

Have you tried warming up (performance of query after executing query for first)? What's the performance after warming up? If it's same as the previous one there might be page faults.

If you are going to run it as an analysis I think warming up the database might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your approach is so slow.

But you might want to try these alternative approaches:

1. Use [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) with many ids at once. I'm not sure if mongodb handles millions of values well, but if it does not, sort the list of IDs and then split it into batches.
2. Do a collection scan in the application and check each entry against a hashset containing the interesting IDs. Should have acceptable performance for a one-off script, especially since you're interested in so many IDs.